# Digital image reconstruction with bit planes

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, bit-manipulation

I am trying to reconstruct an image from extracted bit planes.

Firstly I show the original picture and secondly the pictures per bit-plane.

Here is my code:

```
I = imread('myphoto.jpg');
A=bitget(I,1); subplot(3,3,1), imshow(logical(A));title('Bit plane 1');
A=bitget(I,2); subplot(3,3,2), imshow(logical(A));title('Bit plane 2');
A=bitget(I,3); subplot(3,3,3), imshow(logical(A));title('Bit plane 3');
A=bitget(I,4); subplot(3,3,4), imshow(logical(A));title('Bit plane 4');
A=bitget(I,5); subplot(3,3,5), imshow(logical(A));title('Bit plane 5');
A=bitget(I,6); subplot(3,3,6), imshow(logical(A));title('Bit plane 6');
A=bitget(I,7); subplot(3,3,7), imshow(logical(A));title('Bit plane 7');
A=bitget(I,8); subplot(3,3,8), imshow(logical(A));title('Bit plane 8');
```

Now I want to reconstruct my photo using the bit plane photos. I must start from the most important bit adding the next most important bit etc. I must show all the photos together. I wrote some code like this but I am not sure if this is right.

```
M1 = bitget(A,8)*2^0;
M2 = bitget(A,7)*2^1;
M3 = bitget(A,6)*2^2;
M4 = bitget(A,5)*2^3;
M5 = bitget(A,4)*2^4;
M6 = bitget(A,3)*2^5;
M7 = bitget(A,2)*2^6;
M8 = bitget(A,1)*2^7;

figure,subplot(3,3,1),imshow(M1); subplot(3,3,2),imshow(M2); subplot(3,3,3),imshow(M3); subplot(3,3,4),imshow(M4); subplot(3,3,5),imshow(M5); subplot(3,3,6),imshow(M6); subplot(3,3,7),imshow(M7); subplot(3,3,8),imshow(M8);
```

Comment: "but I am not sure if this is right." Well the best way to see if it is right is to run it! I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: Of course i have run it. The first part is running well but the second part of code which is about reconstruction it doesn't running well

Comment: well describe exactly what the problem is, and ask a specific question. This might help: [ask].

Answer (score 0):

With each `A=bitget(I,...);` you overwrite the previous `A`.  There's no hope of getting back the image this way.  Store each one and then you can get it back.

```
I  = imread('cameraman.tif');
for ib = 1:8, A{ib}=bitget(I,ib); end
```

Each bit-plane is in now a cell of `A` (`clear A` first if it errors).

Reconstruct by summation:

```
Iout = zeros(size(I),'like',I);
for ib = 1:8, Iout = Iout + A{ib}*(2^(ib-1)); end
```

Or use `bitset`, in the spirit of your exercise:

```
Iout = zeros(size(I),'like',I);
for ib = 1:8, Iout = bitset(Iout,ib,A{ib}); end
```

For images with integer-valued pixels, it should be lossless:

```
>> isequal(I,Iout)
ans =
     1
```

Comment: i tried to reconstruct my image with the following code but i can't see the 8 photos which i reconstruct. Here is my code:
`Iout=zeros(size(I),I);
Iout=Iout+ A1*(2^0);subplot(3,3,1),imshow(logical(A1));
Iout=Iout+ A2*(2^1); subplot(3,3,2), imshow(logical(A2));
Iout=Iout+ A3*(2^2); subplot(3,3,3), imshow(logical(A3));
Iout=Iout+ A4*(2^3); subplot(3,3,4),imshow(logical(A4));
Iout=Iout+ A5*(2^4);subplot(3,3,5),imshow(logical(A5));
Iout=Iout+ A6*(2^5);subplot(3,3,6),imshow(logical(A6));
Iout=Iout+ A7*(2^6);subplot(3,3,7),imshow(logical(A7));
Iout=Iout+ A8*(2^7);subplot(3,3,8),imshow(logical(A8));`